# Amazon Elastic Beanstalk trigger deployment without pushing code

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

At the moment the only means I know of to trigger the deployment process (e.g. install packages, execute commands etc.) is to do git aws.push.

Is it possible to trigger the deployment without also pushing code out?

The use case I'm thinking of is where the deployment fails because of incorrect EC2 config for instance and I would like to be able to trigger the deployment process sans code push after fixing the config issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You have at least two options.

- Command line with `eb update`:

  ```
  bender:angry-whopper demo$ eb update
  Update environment? [y/n]: y
  Updating environment "angry-whopper-dev". This may take a few minutes.
  ```
- Web console with "Restart App Server(s)":

[image]

Comment: I think restarting the app server (i.e. tomcat) takes down the entire thing, not the application in the app server. That is bad. What I would want to see is the environment scale up, terminate an instance, and repeat until all instances have been restarted. I suspect that's what the OP wanted too.